# sql query to select multiple items in sorted order

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am writing a post `api in c#` to select some values in `Azure Cosmos db` and is using direct sql queries.

The aim to get the highest value against each id from the request.

**request body:**

```
[
  {
     "userid":"1"
  },
  {
     "userid":"4"
  }     
]
```

**Db looks like:**

```
{
  "userid":"1",
  "value":"10",
  "Date":"10-9-19"
}

{
  "userid":"1",
  "value":"20",
  "Date":"11-8-19"
}

{
  "userid":"4",
  "value":"30",
  "Date":"10-9-19"
}

{
  "userid":"4",
  "value":"40",
  "Date":"11-9-19"
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
 {
  "userid":"4",
  "value":"40",
  "Date":"11-9-19"
 },
 {
  "userid":"1",
  "value":"20",
  "Date":"11-8-19"
 }
]
```

I tried to get the id's into an array then used **'IN'** operator, but it would be helpful and appreciated is there more simple query would help.

Comment: What's is your SQL Server version? it looks like you are storing JSON data in your table.

Comment: As mentioned above am using azure cosmos db

Comment: Thanks DhineshDB will check and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following to get the results.

As per your data, this will work.

```
SELECT userid, 
    MAX(value) value,
    MAX(Date) Date
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY userid
```

If you want related date for the **MAX(Value)**, then try this.

```
SELECT Y.userid, Y.Value, Y.Date 
FROM YourTable Y
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT userid, 
        MAX(value) value
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY userid
    )D ON D.userid = Y.userid AND D.value = Y.value
```

Comment: thanks Dinesh, i also want to include the date field along as updated

Comment: @arunraj414, I can't get your question clearly. You want the MAX date or related date for the MAX value?

Comment: related date for max value, always the date may not be greater. like i updated

Comment: but there is no ROW_NUMBER() in azure cosmos db